# XML to HTML using XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a XML code like

```
<ENREF>12</ENREF>
```

I would like to convert it using XSLT as

```
<small><sup><a id="12" href="#fn12">12</a></sup></small>
```

but it's not up to mark as I'm trying.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this XML:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="hello.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<doc>
    <ENREF>12</ENREF>
</doc>
```

And this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="ENREF">
    <small>
      <sup>
        <xsl:element name="a">
          <xsl:attribute name="id">enref-<xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="href">#fn<xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
      </sup>
    </small>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You'll get the following output:

```
<small>
   <sup>
     <a id="enref-12" href="#fn12">12</a>
   </sup>
</small>
```

Note: I put "enref-" in front of the "12" since HTML ids can't start with a number.

Comment: Sir, I'm using the following XML and XSLT but I'm not getting the required output.

Comment: @UmeshChandraKahali What output are you getting instead?  How are you viewing the files?  A quick way to test this would be to save the XML as "hello.xml", and save the XSLT in the same directory, naming it "hello.xsl".  Then open hello.xml in a modern web browser and tell me what you see.